# What is the name of this plant with wide green leaves that develop splits/holes as they grow?

Tags: identification

It has very large leaves and does not flower (at least I have never seen mine flower).
It grows very wide, with thin stems (seen in picture below). The young leaves will start without any holes in them, and as time goes they split and leaf has openings on them.

I would like to know what the name of this plant is, as I though it was Elephant Ears plant, but further research showed that it is not the case.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [*Monstera deliciosa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstera_deliciosa) Liebm. from [*Araceae*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araceae) family. The flowers usually appear within three years. The plant has a fruit too that is edible **only** when fully mature.

[image: Karl Wimmi -]